# Kel Maleh Rachamim for Jewish martyrs

Tags: tefilla, holocaust-shoah, yizkor

I am looking for variant texts of Kel Maleh Rachamim for the shoah, for Jewish martyrs generally, and for members of the IDF who perished in battle.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D#.D7.9C.D7.96.D7.9B.D7.A8_.D7.A7.D7.95.D7.A8.D7.91.D7.A0.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.94.D7.A9.D7.95.D7.90.D7.94

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D#.D7.9C.D7.96.D7.9B.D7.A8_.D7.97.D7.9C.D7.9C.D7.99_.D7.A6.D7.94.22.D7.9C

Comment: Have you tried looking for these texts on Google? What did you find? What are you missing? Is there a certain format you want? [Edit]ing your post in response to these questions can help you better get the answers you seek.

Answer (score 1):

The ArtScroll Siddur has Keil Maleh for Jewish martyrs and for members of the IDF.

Answer (score 0):

Here are [Tefilos from Yad V'Shem](http://www.yadvashem.org/yv/en/education/ceremonies/pdf/diary2_tehilim.pdf) for holocaust victims.